# How to use array in VBA to capture unique value then update a cell

Tags: excel, vba, match

I have below VBA script. where Cell "mws.Cells(n, 2)" and "mws.Cells(n, 3)" having duplicate value separated by comma. how do i make sure these two cell value have unique value separated by comma ??

```
Sub Summarize()
    Dim i, n As Long, ws, ws1, ws2, ws3, ws4, mws As Worksheet, data, k, m, client, value1, value2
    Dim wb1, wb2, wb3, wb4 As Workbook
    Dim dict As Object, rw1 As Long
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary") 'for tracking unique client id's
    Set newExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Dim wsa() As Variant
    rw1 = 0
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\anil\avamar list\backuplist_JCBAMR300P_2022-06-03_1334.xlsx")
    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("backuplist_JCBAMR300P_2022-06-0")
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\anil\avamar list\backuplist_PPBAMR302P_2022-06-03_1336.xlsx")
    Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("backuplist_PPBAMR302P_2022-06-0")
    Set wb3 = Workbooks.Open("C:\anil\avamar list\backuplist_MNBAMR302P_2022-06-03_1346.xlsx")
    Set ws3 = wb3.Sheets("backuplist_MNBAMR302P_2022-06-0")
    Set wb4 = Workbooks.Open("C:\anil\avamar list\backuplist_MNBAMR303P_2022-06-03_1347.xlsx")
    Set ws4 = wb4.Sheets("backuplist_MNBAMR303P_2022-06-0")
    
    Set mws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    wsa = Array(ws1, ws2, ws3, ws4)
    
    For Each ws In wsa
       data = ws.Range("A2:U" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).Value 'data to array
               For n = 2 To mws.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
                            value1 = LCase(mws.Cells(n, 1))
                            For i = 1 To UBound(data, 1)                       'loop over rows in the array
                            value2 = LCase(data(i, 2))
                            If Mid(value2, 1, Len(value1)) = value1 Then   'if client name from mainsheet fuzzy matches to data sheet
                            
                            If Not dict.exists(data(i, 1)) Then   'first time for this client?
                                rw = rw + 1                   'increment "row" counter
                                dict.Add data(i, 1), rw           'store position in dictionary
                            End If
 
                            End If
                            Next
                        
                Next
    
    Next
                        For k = 0 To dict.Count - 1
                        mws.Cells(n, 2) = mws.Cells(n, 2) & " " & dict.Items(k) & "," 'dump dictionary all value in a cell separated by comma
                        Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim i, n As Long, ws, ws1, ws2, ws3, ws4, mws As Worksheet, data, m,` is not doing what you think. Unless specified, these are being classified as varient.

Comment: You can use `Split()` and Dictionaries to check the values: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/dictionary-object

Comment: having error at line "mws.Cells(n, 2) = mws.Cells(n, 2) & " " & dict.Items(k) & ","     any idea what i am missing ?

Comment: "having error" is not a very useful description of the problem - what error are you getting?